# The app with id xxxxxxxx does not have the right view_structure on app with id yyyy

Tags: ios, swift, podio

I'm trying to create a new item in a podio app in an iOS app with. The following lines of code as per the documentation in podio but I am having a 403 error with the subject as the error message. I assumed that I needed to authenticate the session as an app as I think that it will use the app id to create the PKTItem in the app used to sign in.

```
let item = PKTItem(forAppWithID: lastItem + 1) 
item?.setValue(1, forField: "service") 
item?.setValue(testPet, forField: "pet")

item?.save().onComplete({(response, error) in 
    if (error != nil){ 
        print("error: \(error)") 
    } 
    else{ 
        print("response") 
    } 
})
```

I was in the assumption that the item would be created in the app that was used to sign with the item having an id of `lastItem + 1`, I tried to see if the object's IDs are correct

```
//this is supposed to be lastItem + 1
print("PKTItem ID: \(item?.appItemID)")
//this is supposed to be the app ID where it should create the new item
print("PKTItem AppID: \(item?.appID)")

PKTItem ID: Optional(0)
PKTItem AppID: Optional(1)
```

I don't what I was doing wrong. Please assist me.

Comment: I have no idea what podio is but to me the init `PKTItem(forAppWithID:)` should be called with the Id of the app, at least that is how I read `forAppWithID`

Comment: according to the documentation, it should be the item id since they use the id provided there to update the item if the id exists http://podio.github.io/podio-objc/items/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the wrong set of credentials to look at the app item you are attempting to work with. How did you authorize? Do you have the right App ID and Token combination for this script?

Typically you will see `[PodioKit authenticateAutomaticallyAsAppWithID:123456 token:@"my-app-token"];` and that allows you to interact with anything in the the app 123456, but it sounds like you are trying to interact with data in 2 apps based on the error message. If this is a small scale implementation (or for testing purposes) you can use the Authenticate as User method instead. Here is the documentation they have on [Authentication for the Objective C library.](http://podio.github.io/podio-objc/authentication/)

```
PKTAsyncTask *authTask = [PodioKit authenticateAsUserWithEmail:@"myname@mydomain.com" password:@"p4$$w0rD"];

[authTask onComplete:^(PKTResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // Successfully authenticated
  } else {
    // Failed to authenticate, double check your credentials
  }
}];
```

Comment: i am actually using `authenticateAsApp` when i am getting the error (403) when i was using `authenticateAsUser` i'm getting a 404.

Comment: as far as errors in my application this is the only one since i can fetch the items from the selected app flawlessly

Comment: When you authenticate as user, where does the 404 happen? Is it in the authentication, or is it happening on the Get Item call? If it is on the Get Item call, can you try feeding it a specific item id instead of a variable to confirm that it is a 404 issue and not an empty variable issue?

Comment: the 404 was when i was trying to create a PKTItem. i already found the solution on their non objective-c documentation. as per their documentation: "Item updating works very similar to creation, but instead of providing the app id as we do when creating items, you must specify the item id when updating."